# How do you format EcsTextFormatter from Elastic.CommonSchema?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, serilog

I am using the EcsTextFormatter but I see that you can have custom mappings. I want to remove the host field but I am unsure how to do that in custom mapping.

I have it set as such in my code but MapCustom won't take these two arguments.

```
var config = new EcsTextFormatterConfiguration();

        config.MapCustom((EcsDocument ecs1, LogEvent logEvent, EcsDocument ecs2) =>
        {
            ecs.Host = null;
        });
```

However I am receiving this error from MapCustom.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'arg2' of 'Func<EcsDocument, LogEvent, EcsDocument>'   TestPOC
```

Comment: You didn't return value in the mapcustom

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the host property you don't need to provide a function to MapCustom,
you can simply use the IncludeHost configuration option.

```
var config = new EcsTextFormatterConfiguration()
{
    IncludeHost = false
}
```

If you do want to use MapCustom you should change your syntax. MapCustom has two parameters: EcsDocument and LogEvent. It returns a EcsDocument

```
MapCustom = (EcsDocument ecs1, LogEvent logEvent) =>
{
    // Configure ecs2 based on ecs1 and logEvent
    var ecs2 = ...
    return ecs2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it with the new Elastic version:

```
var ecsConfig = new EcsTextFormatterConfiguration<EcsDocument>
{
    MapCustom = (ecsDoc, log) =>
    {
        ecsDoc.Host = null;
        ecsDoc.Service = new Service { Name = config["ElasticApm:ServiceName"] };
        return ecsDoc;
    }
};
var formatter = new EcsTextFormatter(ecsConfig);

logConfig.WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri($"{config["Elastic:Uri"]}"))
{
    CustomFormatter = formatter
});
```